# using genymotion android emulator on netbook

Tags: android, performance

Good day everyone. I am want to know if i can install genymotion on my netbook using intel atom processor @ 1.66GHz and 1GB RAM. I intend to use the genymotion emulator with eclipse during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/. Check this link. I highly doubt it would be a smooth process for you, if you run genymotion on your machine

Answer (score 0):

I have a netbook With 2*1,3Ghz CPU and 4GB RAM. Genymotion runs fine on this machine. It's much slower than on my wokplace computer but its good enough to debug my applications.

But 1GB memory is surely not enough. I assume you need about 1GB for the emulator and additional 1-2 GB for the development tools.